# How can I improve my laptop screen's video quality with dark scenes (color banding)?

Tags: windows, video, display, nvidia-graphics-card, laptop-display

I have an HP ZBook G2 laptop with a DreamColor screen, Nvidia Quadro K5100M graphics adapter, and Windows 10. When I bought the laptop in 2016, it offered multiple choices for screens and graphics adapters, and the DreamColor and Nvidia Quadro K5100M options were by far the most expensive options, so I thought I'd be getting the best image/video quality out of it.

But I have always noticed terrible video quality on this laptop when watching videos with dark scenes. The quality is a lot worse than an older ThinkPad T60 laptop from 2006 with Windows XP.

Here is an example showing the exact same video file on both laptops, playing in VLC media player, paused at the same place (these are photos of the laptops' screens, not screenshots). The newer HP ZBook laptop looks like:

[image]

The older ThinkPad laptop looks like:

[image]

I also took this photo of the HP ZBook laptop duplicating its screen (on the left) to an external monitor (on the right):

[image]

As you can see, the gradations on both the older ThinkPad laptop and the external monitor look very smooth, while they look very rough/pixelated on the newer HP ZBook laptop. Apparently this phenomenon is known as "color banding".

Since the HP ZBook laptop's output to an external monitor looks fine, that would indicate the problem is related to the ZBook's DreamColor screen and not its Nvidia K5100M GPU.

It is extremely disappointing that the HP ZBook's DreamColor screen, which was supposedly the best laptop screen one could buy at that time, looks so much worse than the ThinkPad screen, which is almost 10 years older. Are there any settings I can change in Windows 10 or the Nvidia Control Panel to have the HP ZBook's video quality be more like the ThinkPad and external monitor?

I did see a setting in the Nvidia Control Panel for the "Output color depth", although I'm not sure if that would have any impact on this problem. Currently it is set to "8 bpc", and it shows a "10 bpc" option:

[image]

Unfortunately, when I change it to "10 bpc" and click "Apply", it automatically changes back to "8 bpc". I'm not sure why it won't let me change it to "10 bpc". Everything I have read about the DreamColor screen and Nvidia K5100M tell me that they both support 10-bit color. But I don't know if the ThinkPad with Windows XP supports 10-bit color - if it doesn't, then changing the ZBook to 10-bit probably won't help.

Additional information: I just tried booting up the laptop using a SliTaz Linux Live DVD to see if the problem also happens in a different operating system. I played the exact same video file, and although it is still pixelated in dark scenes, it definitely isn't as bad as it is in Windows.

Comment: Wait. Are these screenshots or photos? If its the former you can rule out the screen. Also what's the video player(s) you are using?

Comment: They are photographs of the screens. Both laptops played the video using VLC media player.

Comment: In that case, could you test the two laptops on an external monitor, as well as compare screenshots ? Just to narrow things down

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: This may be a color calibration/ICC thing. I had a similar (but not so extreme) case with my laptop and it turned out that some Asus utility (GameVisual) was overriding the ICC profile. Disabling the utility got rid of the banding. Anyway, notebookcheck did a review of your laptop with that specific display, and they created an ICC profile for it. You could try applying it to see if it helps (Google `Review-Update-HP-ZBook-15-DreamColor-Workstation.112327.0.html`)

Comment: @BorisB. I downloaded the Display_1.icm file and applied it as described [here](https://pcmonitors.info/articles/using-icc-profiles-in-windows/). Unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Try perhaps from the page of [Software and drivers for HP ZBook 15 G2 Mobile Workstation](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-15-g2-mobile-workstation/6978814) to install the Driver-Graphics package that correlates to your hardware (do you see an Intel display adapter in Device Manager?) and reboot. Create first a System Restore point, in case.

Comment: @harrymc Yes the graphics driver from HP is already installed (and actually it is [this page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-17-g2-mobile-workstation/6978821) since I have the 17 inch screen).

Comment: Pixelation may occur when a non-native resolution is used to display images on the laptop screen. Which resolution are you using in Windows and which in Linux? Are you using the highest that is listed? Note: This interesting Linux driver [patch](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/791235/) puts the blame for the problems on the bad EDID info returned by the screen which confuses the driver. Evidently this fix was only done in Linux.

Comment: @harrymc The screen's native resolution is 1920x1080. That is the resolution I am using for both Windows and Linux.

Comment: In this case, see my update to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! According to a [forum post](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/hp-zbook-17-owners-lounge.751269/page-53#post-11040249):

> As others may have pointed out, on the Dreamcolor display, by default, 10bpc color depth is not selected in the NVIDIA Control Panel. This causes severe color banding on the display, and it looks worse depending on what you're doing. On the latest NVIDIA drivers supplied by HP, if you try and select 10bpc in the control panel, the screen will flicker black, and then it will revert back to 8bpc again, making it impossible to even select 10bpc. Now, if you revert back to driver version 385.73 ( which Windows will also install by default at first system launch if you don't update any drivers via HP's website ), you can get your GPU to output 10bpc

So I installed version 391.33 of the Nvidia [driver](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/132520/en-us) (since I couldn't find version 385.73), and I was finally able to change the "Output color depth" in the Nvidia Control Panel from 8 bpc to 10 bpc. Dark video and images look so much better now!

Not sure why the recent versions of the Nvidia driver don't allow you to increase the color depth to 10 bpc, but I'm glad the older versions are still available.

Comment: This should be available by black balance or gamma.

Answer (score 0):

You may color-calibrate your new monitor to your color preferences.
For a laptop, the success of the below method may depend on the color adjustments
possible for your model, or on utilities supplied by the manufacturer
(you should also look for display software available for download on the
manufacturer's website).

- Run *Settings > Display* and set your resolution to the recommended one
- Enter in the Start menu `calibrate` and click
  "Change advanced colour management settings for displays, scanne..."
- In the "Colour Management" display, go to the "Advanced" tab
- Click "Calibrate display"
- In the dialog that spans your whole screen, click "Next" twice and start
  the calibration process
- You will be able to adjust the display settings of gamma, brightness,
  contrast and color balance, for both Windows and the monitor
  (if your laptop monitor can calibrate these settings)
- And the end you will be able to compare the new and old settings and click
  "Finish" to apply the settings or "Cancel" to discard the new configuration.

For more details with screenshots see the article
[How to calibrate your PC's monitor on Windows 10](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-calibrate-your-pcs-monitor-windows-10).

---

As the above didn't work for the poster, I have done further
research and found an interesting
[Linux driver patch](https://lore.kernel.org/patchwork/patch/791235/)
that mentions that the builtin eDP panel in the HP zBook 17 G2
returns bad
[EDID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data)
info for the screen's depth, so drivers will fall back to a lower
bpc setting.

The Linux driver patch basically overrode the missing data
using the screen's unique identifier, so is able to use the
screen with a better quality.

Such a fix was evidently only done in Linux, while the
Windows driver is still unable to use the screen at its best
quality of 10 bpc.

You may signal the problem to NVIDIA Support, but I don't believe
that there will be any speedy solution to the problem.

Comment: I went through the Windows 10 calibration process as you described, and there is no improvement on the poor quality of dark scenes in videos.

Comment: I see you're still looking for a solution. Try [How to fix Nvidia color banding issues on Windows 10 PCs](https://windowsreport.com/nvidia-color-banding-fix/).

Comment: I just tried it. For step 1, there was nothing to remove. For step 2, I unchecked "Allow task to be run on demand", and it was already disabled, and after rebooting the problem is still happening.

Comment: You might need to accept this as a limitation of the hardware, coupled with a non-optimal Windows driver.

Comment: A lot of people seem to have had this color banding problem with Nvidia GPUs: [link](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/geforce-graphics-cards/5/195771/noticeable-color-banding-in-gradients/?topicPage=2&commentPage=2). It's so strange that they would have the problem that other GPU manufacturers had solved at least 10 years earlier. But then again I'm not sure it is a GPU problem for me - why does my laptop's output to an external monitor not exhibit the problem at all?